# How do I change the font size in Specview?

Tags: specman

I'm using Specman in interactive mode. After replacing a failing hard drive in my machine, Specview has a very small font size. I checked all menus and all the tabs in the configuration options and found nothing. Specman help yielded no results either.

Does anyone know how to increase the font size? It's really small.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the Specman manual, under "Customizing Specview".

Here is a snippet:

> 1.2.6 Customizing Specview The Specman X resources file mostly contains visual parameters relating to fonts, background, splash
>   screen, and the activity indicator. You can change these settings.
>
> To change GUI parameters for Specview:
>
> 1. Copy the specview.resources file to your home directory. % cp specman-install-dir/specman/specview.resources ~/specview.resources
> 2. Edit the copy of the file with any text editor and then save the file.
>
> There are about 5 "font" entries:
>
> - General font
> - Text area font (the main console text)
> - Toolbar and menu font
> - 2 Coverage GUI fonts
>
> If you edit the "12" and change it to some other value the font will
>   increase accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by installing missing fonts, but this actually answers the original question and it works.